# Too many values for a particular key in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a K-Means Clustering code in MapReduce on Hadoop. If I have few number of clusters, consider 2, and if the data is very large, the whole data would be divided into two sets and each Reducer would receive too many values for a particular key, i.e the cluster centroid. How to solve this?

Note: I use the iterative approch to calculate new centers.

Comment: `Reducer would receive too many values for a particular key`, so what?

Comment: If the data size is very huge, reducer will have to loop through a lot of values right? So won't it be too much work for a single computer?

Comment: `Secondary sort in Mapreduce` https://gist.github.com/airawat/6604175

Comment: I thank you for the anser but I cannot seem to understand how will I apply this to my problem.

Comment: Will it be the same as using a combiner function?

Comment: it would help, if you described the logic of your algorithm, at least.

Comment: Okay. I just find the distance between all the data points and the centers, find the minimum distance centroid, and then assign that data point as value to the centroid which serves as the key. At the reducer, I just average out all the values and create new center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithmically, there is not much you can do, as the nature of this algorithm is the one that you describe. The only option, in this respect, is to use more clusters and divide your data to more reducers, but this yields a different result.

So, the only thing that you can do, in my opinion, is compressing. And I do not only mean, using a compression codec of Hadoop.

For instance, you could find a compact representation of your data. E.g., give an integer id to each element and only pass this id to the reducers. This will save network traffic (store elements as `VIntWritables`, or define your own `VIntArrayWritable` extending `ArrayWritable`) and memory of each reducer.

In this case of k-means, I think that a combiner is not applicable, but if it is, it would greatly reduce the network and the reducer's overhead.

EDIT: It seems that you CAN use a combiner, if you follow [this iterative implementation](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~veronika/MAE/parallelkmeansmapreduce_zhao.pdf). Please, edit your question to describe the algorithm that you have implemented.

Comment: Yeah you can use a combiner. However, also a neat trick is to shard the data across multiple reducers by changing the key a bit. I was using a small pools of randoms appended to the "cluster_id" to shard across reducers. Then the local job supervisor would merge the small shards back together for the centers in the next iteration. It's the same gist as using a combiner.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vefthym for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasJungblut, that is a very interesting approach!

Answer (score -1):

If you have too much shuffle then you will run into OOM issues.

Try to split the dataset in smaller chunks and try

yarn.app.mapreduce.client.job.retry-interval
AND
mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.retry-delay.max.ms

where there are more splits but the retries of the job will be long enough so there is no OOM issues.